# Spark Word2vec vector mathematics

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I was looking at the [example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#example) of Spark site for Word2Vec:

```scala
val input = sc.textFile("text8").map(line => line.split(" ").toSeq)

val word2vec = new Word2Vec()

val model = word2vec.fit(input)

val synonyms = model.findSynonyms("country name here", 40)
```

How do I do the interesting vector such as king - man + woman = queen. I can use model.getVectors, but not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 22):

Here is an example in `pyspark`, which I guess is straightforward to port to Scala - the key is the use of `model.transform`.

First, we train the model as in the example:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec

sc = SparkContext()
inp = sc.textFile("text8_lines").map(lambda row: row.split(" "))

k = 220         # vector dimensionality
word2vec = Word2Vec().setVectorSize(k)
model = word2vec.fit(inp)
```

`k` is the dimensionality of the word vectors - the higher the better (default value is 100), but you will need memory, and the highest number I could go with my machine was 220. (**EDIT:** Typical values in the relevant publications are between 300 and 1000)

After we have trained the model, we can define a simple function as follows:

```py
def getAnalogy(s, model):
    qry = model.transform(s[0]) - model.transform(s[1]) - model.transform(s[2])
    res = model.findSynonyms((-1)*qry,5) # return 5 "synonyms"
    res = [x[0] for x in res]
    for k in range(0,3):
        if s[k] in res:
            res.remove(s[k])
    return res[0]
```

Now, here are some examples with countries and their capitals:

```py
s = ('france', 'paris', 'portugal')
getAnalogy(s, model)
# u'lisbon'

s = ('china', 'beijing', 'russia')
getAnalogy(s, model)
# u'moscow'

s = ('spain', 'madrid', 'greece')
getAnalogy(s, model)
# u'athens'

s = ('germany', 'berlin', 'portugal')
getAnalogy(s, model)
# u'lisbon'

s = ('japan', 'tokyo', 'sweden')
getAnalogy(s, model)    
# u'stockholm'

s = ('finland', 'helsinki', 'iran')
getAnalogy(s, model)
# u'tehran'

s = ('egypt', 'cairo', 'finland')
getAnalogy(s, model)
# u'helsinki'
```

The results are not always correct - I'll leave it to you to experiment, but they get better with more training data and increased vector dimensionality `k`.

The `for` loop in the function removes entries that belong to the input query itself, as I noticed that frequently the correct answer was the second one in the returned list, with the first usually being one of the input terms.

Comment: Can you please specify why you are multiplying by -1 here:     res = model.findSynonyms((-1)*qry,5) # return 5 "synonyms" Also, can you write some comments about the for loop in your getAnalogy function.

Comment: The example with the same dataset did not work as expected. res = getAnalogy(s, model) print "Result is: " + res o/p is: Result is: montpellier

Comment: 1) ``-1`` is just for keeping the ``qry`` order intuitive; you can change this order and remove it 2) Have already provided comments regarding ``for`` loop; try removing it and returning all of ``res`` (instead of just ``res[0]`` to see why it is necessary 3) Already said that the results are not always correct, but they get better with increasing ``k`` (papers use at least ``k=300``); moreover, exact results depend on the random seed. **All in all**, the answer is exactly about the word2vec mathematics, which is what the question was about.

Comment: @user3803714 Keep also in mind that results shown in publications and demos are always hand-picked, i.e. the mistaken results are simply not shown (although they indeed exist).

Answer (score 1):

```
  val w2v_map = sameModel.getVectors//this gives u a map {word:vec}

  val (king, man, woman) = (w2v_map.get("king").get, w2v_map.get("man").get, w2v_map.get("women").get)

  val n = king.length

  //daxpy(n: Int, da: Double, dx: Array[Double], incx: Int, dy: Array[Double], incy: Int);
  blas.saxpy(n,-1,man,1,king,1)

  blas.saxpy(n,1,woman,1,king,1)

  val vec = new DenseVector(king.map(_.toDouble))

  val most_similar_word_to_vector = sameModel.findSynonyms(vec, 10) //they have an api to get synonyms for word, and one for vector
  for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- most_similar_word_to_vector) {
    println(s"$synonym $cosineSimilarity")
  }
```

and the running result as below:

```
women 0.628454885964967
philip 0.5539534290356802
henry 0.5520055707837214
vii 0.5455116413024774
elizabeth 0.5290994886254643
**queen 0.5162519562606844**
men 0.5133851770249461
wenceslaus 0.5127030522678778
viii 0.5104392579985102
eldest 0.510425791249559
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is the pseudo code. For the full implementation, read the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2VecModel.html

1. `w2v_map = model.getVectors() # this gives u a map {word:vec}`
2. `my_vector = w2v_map.get('king') - w2v_map.get('man') + w2v_map.get('queen') # do vector algebra here`
3. `most_similar_word_to_vector = model.findSynonyms(my_vector, 10) # they have an api to get synonyms for word, and one for vector`

edit: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2VecModel.html#findSynonyms(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector,%20int)

Comment: Not clear how to do the vector match. Breeze or Spark vectors? That has is a key component of the question....

Comment: public scala.Tuple2<String,Object> findSynonyms(Vector vector, int num)

You do vector match with this method that I listed: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2VecModel.html#findSynonyms(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector,%20int)