# how to load a word2vec model and call its function into the mapper

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I want to load a word2vec model and evaluate it by executing word analogy tasks (e.g. *a is to b as c is to something?*). To do this, first I load my w2v model:

```py
model = Word2VecModel.load(spark.sparkContext, str(sys.argv[1]))
```

and then I call the mapper to evaluate the model:

```py
rdd_lines = spark.read.text("questions-words.txt").rdd.map(getAnswers)
```

The `getAnswers` function reads one line per time from *questions-words.txt*, in which each line contains the question and the answer to evaluate my model (e.g. Athens Greece Baghdad Iraq, where a=Athens, b=Greece, c=Baghdad and something=Iraq). After reading the line, I create the `current_question` and the `actual_answer` (e.g.: `current_question=Athens Greece Baghdad` and `actual_answer=Iraq`). After that, I call the `getAnalogy` function that is used to compute the analogy (basically, given the question it computes the answer). Finally, after computing the analogy, I return the answer and write it to a text file.

The problem is that I get the following exception:

```py
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers.
```

and I think that it is thrown because I am using the model within the map function. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448456/using-word2vecmodel-transform-does-not-work-in-map-function) is similar to my problem but I do not know how to apply that answer to my code. How can I solve this problem? The following is the full code:

```py
def getAnalogy(s, model):
    try:
        qry = model.transform(s[0]) - model.transform(s[1]) - model.transform(s[2])    
        res = model.findSynonyms((-1)*qry,5) # return 5 "synonyms"
        res = [x[0] for x in res]
        for k in range(0,3):
            if s[k] in res:
                res.remove(s[k])
        return res[0]
    except ValueError:
        return "NOT FOUND"

def getAnswers (text):
    tmp = text[0].split(' ', 3)
    answer_list = []
    current_question = " ".join(str(x) for x in tmp[:3])
    actual_answer = tmp[-1]

    model_answer = getAnalogy(current_question, model)
    if model_answer is "NOT FOUND":
        answer_list.append("NOT FOUND\n")
    elif model_answer is actual_answer:
        answer_list.append("TRUE\n")
    else:
        answer_list.append("FALSE:\n")
    return answer_list.append


if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: my_test <file>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)


    spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("my_test")\
    .getOrCreate()


    model = Word2VecModel.load(spark.sparkContext, str(sys.argv[1]))

    rdd_lines = spark.read.text("questions-words.txt").rdd.map(getAnswers)

    dataframe = rdd_lines.toDF()

    dataframe.write.text(str(sys.argv[2]))

    spark.stop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already suspected, you cannot use the model in a map function. On the other hand, the `questions-answers.txt` file is not that big (~ 20K lines), so you should better do the evaluation using vanilla Python list comprehensions (it is essentially the first suggested answer in the question you have linked); it is not fast, but it is just an one-off task. Here is a way, using [my `getAnalogy` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172242/spark-word2vec-vector-mathematics/34298583#34298583) as you have augmented it for error handling (notice that I have already removed the 'comment' lines from `questions-answers.txt`, and that you should convert it to lowercase, something you don't seem to be doing in your code):

```py
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec, Word2VecModel
model = Word2VecModel.load(sc, "word2vec/demo_200") # model built with k=200
with open('/home/ctsats/word2vec/questions-words.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines2 = [x.lower() for x in lines] # all to lowercase
lines3 = [x.strip('\n') for x in lines2] # remove end-of-line characters
lines4 = [x.split(' ',3) for x in lines3]
lines4[0] # check:
# ['Athens', 'Greece', 'Baghdad', 'Iraq']

def getAnswers (text, model):
    actual_answer = text[-1]
    question = [text[0], text[1], text[2]]
    model_answer = getAnalogy(question, model)
    if model_answer == "NOT FOUND":
        correct_answer = "NOT FOUND"
    elif model_answer == actual_answer:
        correct_answer = "TRUE"
    else:
        correct_answer = "FALSE"
    return text, model_answer, correct_answer
```

So, your evaluation list can now be built as

```py
answer_list = [getAnswers(x, model) for x in lines4]
```

Here's an example for the first 20 entries (with a model of `k=200`):

```py
[(['athens', 'greece', 'baghdad', 'iraq'], u'turkey', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'bangkok', 'thailand'], u'turkey', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'beijing', 'china'], u'albania', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'berlin', 'germany'], u'germany', 'TRUE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'bern', 'switzerland'], u'liechtenstein', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'cairo', 'egypt'], u'albania', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'canberra', 'australia'], u'liechtenstein', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'hanoi', 'vietnam'], u'turkey', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'havana', 'cuba'], u'turkey', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'helsinki', 'finland'], u'finland', 'TRUE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'islamabad', 'pakistan'], u'turkey', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'kabul', 'afghanistan'], u'albania', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'london', 'england'], u'italy', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'madrid', 'spain'], u'portugal', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'moscow', 'russia'], u'russia', 'TRUE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'oslo', 'norway'], u'albania', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'ottawa', 'canada'], u'moldova', 'FALSE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'paris', 'france'], u'france', 'TRUE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'rome', 'italy'], u'italy', 'TRUE'),
 (['athens', 'greece', 'stockholm', 'sweden'], u'norway', 'FALSE')]
```

Comment: thanks, this is definitely a good alternative but the problem is that I have to evaluate many models, and I would like to  call the w2v model functions (e.g. findSynonyms()) within the map function.

Comment: As I said, there is simply no way of doing this with Spark. Alternatively, you could try another word2vec implementation (e.g. gensim) and include this in your map function.

Comment: ok I see..... but how can I save a w2v model with pyspark and then load it with gensim? The problem is that the w2v model saved with pyspark is a set of parquet files, while gensim stores ".model" file (and not parquet)...

Comment: @Juniorhpc you can't do that; you must build & save the model with gensim, and then include this gensim model in your map function (haven't tested it though)