# How to obtain the word list from pyspark word2vec model?

Tags: apache-spark, nlp, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I am trying to generate word vectors using PySpark. Using gensim I can see the words and the closest words as below:

```python
sentences = open(os.getcwd() + "/tweets.txt").read().splitlines()
w2v_input=[]
for i in sentences:
    tokenised=i.split()
    w2v_input.append(tokenised)
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(w2v_input)
for key in model.wv.vocab.keys():
    print key
    print model.most_similar(positive=[key])
```

Using PySpark

```python
inp = sc.textFile("tweet.txt").map(lambda row: row.split(" "))
word2vec = Word2Vec()
model = word2vec.fit(inp)
```

How can I generate the words from the vector space in model? That is the pyspark equivalent of the gensim `model.wv.vocab.keys()`?

Background: I need to store the words and the synonyms from the model in a map so I can use them later for finding the sentiment of a tweet. I cannot reuse the word-vector model in the map functions in pyspark as the model belongs to the spark context (error pasted below). I want the pyspark word2vec version instead of gensim because it provides better synonyms for certain test words.

```python
 Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation.SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers.
```

Any alternative solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent command in Spark is `model.getVectors()`, which again returns a dictionary. Here is a quick toy example with only 3 words (`alpha, beta, charlie`), adapted from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec):

```python
sc.version
# u'2.1.1'

from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec
sentence = "alpha beta " * 100 + "alpha charlie " * 10
localDoc = [sentence, sentence]
doc = sc.parallelize(localDoc).map(lambda line: line.split(" "))
word2vec = Word2Vec()
model = word2vec.fit(doc)

model.getVectors().keys()
#  [u'alpha', u'beta', u'charlie']
```

Regarding finding synonyms, you may find [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172242/spark-word2vec-vector-mathematics/34298583#34298583) useful.

Regarding the error you mention and a possible workaround, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046843/how-to-load-a-word2vec-model-and-call-its-function-into-the-mapper/41190031#41190031) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

And as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062278/would-model-getvectors-keys-return-all-the-keys-from-a-model), 
if you want to include all the words in your document set the MinCount parameter accordingly (default=5):

```
word2vec = Word2Vec()
word2vec.setMinCount(1)
```