# Would model.getVectors().keys() return all the Keys from a model

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

Below is a sample code. I'm trying to get vector representation for all the words in newfile.txt (file having a news article). Would like to know if model.getVectors().keys() outputs all the keys (distinct words in the file) or does it limits the output to certain number.

Currently I get only a few words as key though my input does have many. How does it work?

```
doc = sc.textFile('newfile.txt').map(lambda line: line.split(" "))

model = Word2Vec().fit(doc)

model.getVectors().keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, all the keys(words) was not listed because of this parameter to the model `setMinCount()`, has a default value of 5

From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2Vec.html)

Thanks for the help !